# Abstract BankAccount

Tags: java, abstract

I'm supposed to make the monthlyProcess in the BankAccount class abstract.

I have a parent class, BankAccount, and its sub class, SavingsAccount. I made the BankAccount class abstract and its monthlyProcess method as well. I guess my problem would be that I don't know how to get the monthlyProcess method in the SavingsAccount class to do what it did in the BankAccount class since I cannot access the variables I need from the Savings class.

I tried creating a new BankAccount constructor and copied what was inside the monthlyProcess method, into the new constructor.

`````
public abstract class BankAccount
{
    // Will hold the account balance
    private double accountBalance;
    // will hold the number of deposits made
    private int numberOfDeposits;
    // Will hold number of withdrawals made
    private int numberOfWithdrawals;
    // will hold the annual interest rate
    private double annualInterestRate;
    // will hold the amount of the monthly service charge
    private double monthlyServiceCharge;
    // will hold the monthly interest rate
    private double monthlyInterestRate;
    // Will hold the amount of monthly interest
private double monthlyInterest; 

    // Constructor accepts arguments for the balance and interest rate
    public BankAccount(double initialBalance, double interest)
    {
        accountBalance = initialBalance;

        annualInterestRate = interest;
    }

    public BankAccount()
    {
        accountBalance = accountBalance - monthlyServiceCharge;

        calcInterest();

        numberOfWithdrawals = 0;


        numberOfDeposits = 0;

        monthlyServiceCharge = 0;
    }
    // Method will add the argument it take to the accountBalance variable
    // The number of deposits is incremented
    public void deposit(double deposit)
    {
        accountBalance += deposit;

        numberOfDeposits++;
    }

    // The argument taken will be substracted form the account balance
    // The number of withdrawals is also incremented
    public void withdraw(double withdraw)
    {
        accountBalance -= withdraw;

        numberOfWithdrawals++;
    }

    // Method which determines the interest calculations
    public void calcInterest()
    {
        // Calculation for monthly interest rate
        monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate / 12);

        //Calculation for monthly interst
        monthlyInterest = accountBalance * monthlyInterestRate;

        // Will hold the balance of the account added to the monthly interest
        accountBalance = accountBalance + monthlyInterest;
    }

    public abstract void monthlyProcess();
    /*// Method which determines amount how much interest is owed on account
    public void monthlyProcess()
    {
        accountBalance = accountBalance - monthlyServiceCharge;

        calcInterest();

        numberOfWithdrawals = 0;


        numberOfDeposits = 0;

        monthlyServiceCharge = 0;
    }*/

    //Returns number of withdrawals made
    public int getNumberOfWithdrawals()
    {
        return numberOfWithdrawals;
    }

    // Returns number of deposits made
    public int getNumberOfDeposits()
    {
        return numberOfDeposits;
    }

    public void setMonthlyServiceCharge(double charge)
    {
        monthlyServiceCharge = charge;
    }

    //returns monthly service charge
    public double getMonthlyServiceCharge()
    {
        return monthlyServiceCharge;
    }

    // Returns account balance
    public double getBalance()
    {
        return accountBalance;
    }
}
````
// SavingsAccount will inhert from BankAccount
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount
{
    // boolean variable will be used to determine if account is active
    private boolean status = true;

    // Constrcutor will take an argument for the account balance and interest rate
    public SavingsAccount(double initialBalance, double interest)
    {
        // Will inherit contructor from BankAccount class
        super(initialBalance, interest);

        // If statement used to determine if account is active
        if(initialBalance < 25)
        {
            status = false;
        }
    }

    // Withdraw methof will take away from the bank account balance
    // if the balance falls below 25, the account is inactive
    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        // If statement will determine if the active in order to withdraw
        if(getBalance() < 25)
        {
            status = false;

            System.out.println("Account Inactive: No Withdrawals can be made. ");
        }
        else
        {
            super.withdraw(amount);
        }
    }

    // The deposit method will be used to add funds into the account.
    // Once the account balance is above 25, it becomes active
    public void deposit(double deposit)
    {
        // Determines if account is inactive or active after a deposit has been made
        if(getBalance() < 25)
        {
            status = false;
        }
        else if(getBalance() > 25)
        {
            status = true;
        }

        // Calling the superclass version of the deposit method
        super.deposit(deposit);
    }

    // Method will charge the service fee for having more than four withdrawals 
    public void monthlyProcess()
    {

        // If statement will be used to charge the account for having more than 4 withdrawals 
        if(getNumberOfWithdrawals() > 4)
        {
            setMonthlyServiceCharge((getMonthlyServiceCharge() + getNumberOfWithdrawals()) -4);
        }

        // Calling the superclass version of the monthlyProcess method
        //super.monthlyProcess();



        // will check to see if account is inactive
        if(getBalance() < 25)
        {
            status = false;
        }

        //new SavingsAccount(new(BankAccount));
    }
}
`````

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What are you trying to achieve? does the code compile? are there any errors?

Comment: If you want to do the same in the SavingsAccount.monthlyProcess as in the BankAccount, why is the method abstract?

Comment: The instructions were to make the the BankAccount version of the method abstract @dpr

Comment: @ManojVadehra This is what the monthlyProcess method did before I made it abstract. " A method that subtracts the monthly service charges from the balance, calls the calcInterest method, and then sets the variables that hold the number of withdrawals, number of deposits, and monthly service charges to zero."

Comment: The most obvious solution is to make the `BankAccount` member variables `protected` and simply move the old `monthlyProcess` method into `SavingsAccount` as-is while making the new one abstract.  Why aren't you doing it that way?

Comment: I was told to not use protected variables @Tibrogargan

Comment: Ok, so what is the lesson you're doing trying to teach?  (What's the title?)

Comment: Can you show us the `SavingsAccount` implementation?

Comment: If `BankAccount` and `SavingsAccount` are located in the same package, it's sufficient to remove the `private`access modifier from the fields in Bank account. This way, you avoid using `protected`. You use default (package private) visibility and will be able to access the `BankAccount` member variables from your `SavingsAccount` subclass.